# Firewall blocking UDP for WebRTC Video Chat

Tags: javascript, tcp, udp, webrtc, turn

I am attempting to make a simple videochatting application. However, I am unable to have a video call with a participant who is on a public or corporate wifi network due to UDP packets being blocked.

I have already attempted to create a TURN server and added it into the iceServer config under RTCMultiConnection.js (from Muaz Khan's guide). This helped me open ports and is set to transport=tcp and transport=udp, however it still does not allow access for UDP packets.

This works in my house and from my phone's personal hotspot perfectly fine.

Is there a way to bypass this UDP block from either the server or client side without the use of VPNs, Remote Desktops, etc.?